# Which Activity / Fragment / FragmentManager?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

I am new to Android programming and I am totally lost about from which Activity and Fragment version i shall derive and which FragmentManager I shall use.
I want to support API level 15 and above and I want to use androidx/Jetpack.
So, from which Activity implementation should my MainActivity derive? And from which Fragment implementation shall my fragments derive? Which FragmentManager implementation shall I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity should derive from `AppCompatActivity`.

From https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-app-anatomy/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#2

> AppCompatActivity is a subclass of Activity that supports all modern Android features while providing backward compatibility with older versions of Android. To make your app available to the largest number of devices and users possible, always use AppCompatActivity.

In general, as a rule, you should have a look at the package, if there is a `androidx` package (previously it was android support) which has the class type you are looking for use this one, as they have backwards compatibility.

Another way of knowing which activity to use is using the android studio menus, if you create a new activity (File  / New / Activity / Basic activity) you can see that the generated file uses `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`.

The same goes for the fragments Fragment (File / New / Fragment) and then you go to the source file you can see `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` in the imports. Use this one.

And about the FragmentManager if you search for an androidx package with FragmentManager you'll get `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`.

Quoting https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-images-compat/#5

> Tip: In general, if your app can use a compatibility class from the Jetpack libraries, it should use one of those classes, because those classes provide support for the largest possible number of features and devices.

refering to classes with the `androidx` namespace.

Comment: great, thank you! Confirms what I expected. Note however, that templates in Android Studio can be outdated, so this isn't a reliable source. Especially dependencies are outdated ):

Comment: They could be outdated, however, I've been developing android apps for some years now and I've seen these templates been updated many times (each time there have been changes that affect them). That's why I find them highly reliable and I use them as a trustful source.